# React Native "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, native, uimanager

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FYzS.png)

Hi, in 1 week I have a problem. I added navigation step by step but I'm not resolve the problem.

My project run in ios smoothly but not working in android.

I'm waiting for your information and opinion.

Thank you

I created a new project and added navigation but not solving this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.